# Help identifying signature

Tags: handwriting

I am trying to identify what I'm assuming is a name or signature written in Japanese. The author of the note was a German/Japanese American, and he wrote the note to identify the name of an artist in 1928.[image]
The character is directly after the English word "by" written in script. Thank you for any assistance, including letting me know this is not Japanese or undecipherable if either is the case.

Comment: What is his name?

Comment: That's the problem, I'm unsure who the artist is. The only identifucation is with this character. The author of the note was Sadakichi Hartmann. It is possible he was identifying himself because he did paint pastels.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like it could be an extremely slanted version of *by 「キ」* except that the Japanese "parentheses" 「」 are on the other side, as is customary for vertical (top-to-bottom) writing:

> ﹁
>   キ
>   ﹂

キ would be read as *ki* and it probably isn't intended as a word, but could be an "initial" (although that's not customary in Japan), something like "K".

Comment: Maybe I should add that this is just a wild guess. As you can see, キ is usually slanted the other way...

Comment: Perhaps it's meant to be a mirror image, which would correct the slant and the quotes?

Comment: Who (apart from da Vinci) writes mirrored?

Comment: He was fairly eccentric.

Comment: This 「キ」 looks just fine to me. I guess he simply wanted to "italicize" the letter キ because it's placed on the right of the slanted 'by'.